# How can i show text from hidden state in PHP

Tags: javascript, html, css, hide, show

So i just copy&pasted the code from w3schools "Toggle Hide and Show"

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

and

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Tutorial</button>
<div id="myDIV">
    <p>Rules blablablabla.</p>
</div>
```

really simple code but i'm not good with javascript, i want the div to be hidden at start and then when i click the button, it shows the div.
Sorry for a such an amateur question and thanks !

Comment: You just need to throw a `style="display: none;"` on the div element so it starts out hidden.  Or make a CSS rule: `#myDIV { display: none; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to stackoverflow!

If you want your code to be **hidden at first**, add `style="display:none;"` to your HTML code. This puts CSS styling on your HTML element.

It would look something like this

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Tutorial</button>
<div id="myDIV" style="display:none">
    <p>Rules blablablabla.</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! But i have another problem, i have a while cycle with "<?php echo 'blablabla' then ?> and <button type="submit" name="editlapu" onclick="myFunction()">EDIT</button> and a bit further i have an if cycle, with <div id="editosana" style="display:none;"><?php echo '<h1>ID="'.$row["id"].'" Title="'.$row["title"].'" and so on with forms, inputs, textareas and then in the end outside of php cycle is </div> but when i click the button in the website it only shows it for like a half a second, then closes, each time i click on it. Would you know how to fix that ?